# Time-out expirando mais rápido do que o esperado - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, web.config

Eu estou com uma aplicação que está funcionando ok, porém, quando eu passo um pequeno tempo sem interagir com a página a autenticação do usuário cai e o sistema retorna para a tela de login. eu estou tentando setar esse tempo para 20 minutos no web config porém não consegui.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="20" />
</authentication>

<sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
```

...

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
    <machineKey decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" />
```

em app settings

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000" />
```

eu vi tudo no meu IIS, olhei nos fóruns da microsoft e em outras postagens aqui do SO, porém a sessão continua caindo muito rápido (coisa de um minuto ou dois)...

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SO-português. Para obter respostas aqui, sua pergunta deve estar em português. Você pode traduzí-la, ou pode postar em ingles no stack overflow (inglês).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algumas possibilidades:

- Algum aspecto da aplicação está programaticamente ajustando o valor do timeout de sessão via `Session.Timeout`;
- Algum processo está modificando arquivos monitorados (como `web.config`, ou conteúdo do diretório `bin`) no diretório da aplicação, forçando a reinicialização do pool;
- O cookie de sessão pode estar sendo excluído/destruído.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente seu web.config está correto. Pode ser que o que eu fale agora seja besteira, mas já passei por algumas situações onde uma aplicação estava em um diretório virtual e as configurações da aplicação principal prevaleciam sobre a aplicação interna, verifique se este não é o seu caso.

Espero que isto te ajude de alguma forma.